# Disconnectedcontext was detected

Tags: vb.net, com, database-connection

> Context 0x33a140 is disconnected.  No proxy will be used to service the request on the COM 
>   component. This may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please ensure that 
>   all contexts/apartments stay alive until the application is completely done with the 
>   RuntimeCallableWrappers that represent COM components that live inside them.

I'm setting my `frm_main` as the startup form and then calling `frm_login` on `frm_main_shown`.
I'm using fingerprint reader (digital persona)

When `verification_oncomplete` event fires I'm using the following code for accessing MySQL database.

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection(_con_string)
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Try
        con.Open() <--- this line occurs the error
        'my code here
    catch ex as exception

    finally
         cmd.dispose
         con.close
         con.dispose
    end try
```

Comment: One small thing, use the [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/htd05whh.aspx) statement, e.g. `Using con As New MySqlConnection(_con_string)`

Comment: not solved... same error at con.open @szymon